# Scrolling over ad control-Windows UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, uwp

I am using Microsoft advertising sdk to show ads in the uwp app with test values. Ads are showing properly. But, my concern is once the ad is loaded i was not able to scroll over the ad to top or bottom. I am using ad control inside the scroll viewer. But, i am not able to scroll.
I am trying with following code.
Is it possible to scroll over the ad if not is there any way to scroll because users will feel uneasy if the ad is loaded in bottom with the height i have specified.

```
<Scrollviewer>
<Grid Background="Gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <UI:AdControl
                        AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                        ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                        AdUnitId="10865270"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="250"
                        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="5,20,5,5"
                        Width="300"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <UI:AdControl
                        AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                        ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                        AdUnitId="10865270"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="250"
                        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="5,10,5,5"
                        Width="300"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <UI:AdControl
                        AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                        ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                        AdUnitId="10865270"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="250"
                        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="5,20,5,5"
                        Width="300"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</Scrollviewer>
```

Comment: I tested this code, it can scroll well, what's your problem?

Comment: are you testing in emulator or in phone? If emulator, please check in phone

Comment: I just tested on a Lumia640, it also works well. I can scroll up and down on the phone.

Comment: did you scroll over the ad or on the space which is there on the right or left? Because i am not able to scroll over the ad, i.e., it displays the ad with Microsoft text, so if i scroll over the text it is not scrolling. If we scroll over white space it works fine.

Comment: OK, I got it. In that case, it is by design. Details please reference the same thread you asked on MSDN..

Comment: I didn't get what they are saying in MSDN. What is mean by "by design"?. What i have to do now?